# Get data from a website with Java

Tags: java, web-scraping, web

I tried to get some data from the Amazon website with this code:

```
public class Bot {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader buff;
        InputStreamReader inStream;
        String htmlCode = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://www.amazon.it/gp/bestsellers/electronics/473246031/ref=s9_dnav_bw_ir12_z?pf_rd_m=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_r=1VC27Z69NFM1FJAR2YNY&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=245982287&pf_rd_i=412609031");
            URLConnection urlConnection = (URLConnection)url.openConnection();



            inStream = new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            buff = new BufferedReader(inStream);

            while(true){
                if (buff.readLine()!=null){
                    htmlCode += buff.readLine() + "\n";
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }

            int startFrom = htmlCode.indexOf("<div class=\"zg_rank\">");
            int endFrom = htmlCode.indexOf("</div>");

            String idNumber = htmlCode.substring(startFrom, endFrom);

            System.out.println(idNumber);
        }catch(Exception e){};  

    }

}
```

So what did I wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Please describe what is your problem in more detail. Also, don't swallow the exceptions.

Comment: I think the problem is that when I put the html source in the htmlCode It is different from the real code and so, when I make a substring with the startFrom and endFrom It doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

No my friend, your code is correct. However, a string instance cannot hold the whole page.
Here is how you point from the beginning to the end of your div in question:

```
boolean CodeNeeded = false;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // Here I Point on the beginig of the Code needed
    if(line.contains("<div class=\"zg_rank\">")){
        CodeNeeded = true;
    }

    // Here I Point on the End of the Code needed
    if (line.contains("</div>")) {
        CodeNeeded = false;
    }        
    // If the Code is needed Stored it in DivWanted
    if(CodeNeeded) {
        DivWanted += line + "\n";
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use telepathy, and I think it worked!

I think your problem is the `endFrom`. Try this:

```
int endFrom = htmlCode.lastIndexOf("</div>"); // lastIndexOf, not indexOf
```

Otherwise, you'll only get up to the *first* `</div>`

**EDITED:**

To get the *next* `</div>` after your start, use this:

```
int endFrom = htmlCode.indexOf("</div>", startFrom); // Add 2nd parameter
```

Comment: Ok :) ,with lsatIndexOf I get the first </div> after the startFrom index?? :)

Comment: It doesn't work as I need. Because I need the content of the 2 tag
<div class="zg_rank"> 1 </div>
The program must print 1 and not what it prints now.
How can I get the index of the </div> after the <div class="zg_rank"> ??? Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen JSoup?  It'll make doing this kind of scraping much easier.

Comment: I'll try it now. BTW Try to print the HTMLCode and compare it with the code that you can see by the browser for example using firebug, why It is different??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to try something like that:

```
int startFrom = htmlCode.indexOf("<div class=\"zg_rank\">");
int endFrom = htmlCode.indexOf("</div>", startFrom);
```

Than you search first `</div>` appearance after `<div class="zg_rank">`.